# I'm looking for serial port monitoring software

Tags: windows-7, linux, 64-bit, serial-port, rs232

I need a serial port monitoring software that works on windows 7 64bit or GNU/Linux and supports at least RS-232. Bonus points are if it's free software or at least freeware. I just need to be able to see what goes in and what goes out of the port. At this time, I don't need any protocol deciphering or anything else complicated.

Any ideas on what could work?

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/112957/sniff-serial-port-on-linux

Comment: @Olli Thanks a lot! That fixes the GNU/Linux side of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows machines, I've always used HyperTerminal (`hypertrm.exe`) to monitor serial ports. For my 32-bit Vista install, I copied over `hypertrm.exe` and `hypertrm.dll` from my old XP install and it worked just fine.

I don't have a 64-bit Windows 7 install, so I can't check that it would work for you. So it might need XP compatibility mode or some other 32-bit mode to work.

[This person](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hyperterminal/) got it to work on Windows 7 32-bit. Also on that site is a list of more HyperTerminal replacements for Windows 7, though it focuses much more on the other communication protocols done by HyperTerminal.

Several other HyperTerminal replacement ideas are listed [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/does-windows-7-have-hyperterminal-or-an-equivalent/8ca422a1-ca95-4510-87ca-2ab6bcc7aef7).

Comment: Can hyperterminal show status of each pin on the port?

Comment: I don't have a setup handy to check it out, but I believe the status bar displays active pins `CTS`, `DSR`, etc.